# if function for three time variable in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I need to categorize my data based on three different time slot :

- First shift 19.00-4.00
- second shift 4.00-13.00
- third shift 13.00-19.00.

I used this nested IF Formula but its not working and it returns null for all my data.

```
=IF(AND(B2>=TIMEVALUE("19:01:00"))*(B2<=TIMEVALUE("4:00:00")),"First shift",
 IF(AND(B2>=TIMEVALUE("4:01:00"))*(B2<=TIMEVALUE("13:00:00")),"second shift",
 IF(AND(B2>=TIMEVALUE("13:01:00"))*(B2<=TIMEVALUE("19:00:00")),"third shift","null")))
```

Comment: `*` is a way to shorten `AND()`, and `+` to shorten `OR()`, so pick either `AND(condition1, condition2)` or `(condition1)*(condition2)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(AND(B2<>"",OR(B2<=TIMEVALUE("4:00:00"),B2>TIMEVALUE("19:00:00"))),"First shift",IF(AND(B2>=TIMEVALUE("4:01:00"),B2<=TIMEVALUE("13:00:00")),"second shift",IF(AND(B2>=TIMEVALUE("13:01:00"),B2<=TIMEVALUE("19:01:00")),"third shift","null")))
```

Simpler with a lookup table, say called `shifts`:

```
00:00   First shift
04:01   second shift
13:01   third shift 
19:00   First shift
```

and instead:

```
=IF(B2="","null",VLOOKUP(B2,shifts,2))
```

(which is very similar to @Slai's solution) but neither my first nor second version covers `null` as the output for possibilities such as `time` in B2.

Answer (score 0):

If the value in `B2` is time value, it can be shortened to something like this:

```
=LOOKUP(B2*24, {0,4,13,19,24; "first","second","third","first","???"}) & " shift"
```